# video card to support one large display with 4 rotated monitors

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, resolution, graphics-card

I have four 2560 x 1600 monitors. My goal is to have one huge display that windows thinks is just one monitor, at a resolution of 6400 x 2560.

I've found video cards that support rotating the monitors, so currently I have each monitor rotated, and I have an *effective* display size of 6400  x 2560. However, windows thinks it is 4 separate monitors, and for my purposes I'd like windows to just see one huge monitor. I've found a video card that could do this for two displays side-by-side, but not while they were rotated. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Matrox manufactures graphics cards which should be able to do something like that. Take a look here: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/

Comment: @AndrejaKo: i've tried the Matrox triplehead2go and the NVidia NVS-450. both claimed they could do it (from what I understood from the specs) but both couldn't.

Comment: Well, now we at least know what doesn't work. Did you check out their real cards? Unfortunately, my information about Matrox is pretty old, so I don't know if they have such cards still available.

Answer (score 1):

ATi Eyefinity can do 4x1 in landscape mode or 3x1 in portrait mode. http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/gpu50-ati-eyefinity-display-configs.aspx

Comment: ah this looks promising... will have to investigate. for anyone else who is looking, [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=eyefinity&x=0&y=0)'s a list of a few cards that support eyefinity. will have to see why some cost $120 and others $1200..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at an nvidia card that supports mosaic,  i've used the P4000 todo this a lot,  i recently installed a 3x3 portrait oriented matrix using two p4000 with linked GPU's all super easy to-do through the mosaic control panel.
Mosaic is a free software provided by nividia in the higher end graphics cards.
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/solutions/nvidia-mosaic-technology/